# ffmpeg h264_amf error: CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed with error 10

Tags: ffmpeg, amd-gpu

Trying to transcode a video on a Azure VM with Windows 2019 and with a AMD Radeon instinct MI25 GPU gives this error:

> CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed with error 10

Command used: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_amf output.mp4`

(ffmpeg is compiled with h264_amf support)

I could not find any info on this specific error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [AMD Radeon instinct MI25](https://www.amd.com/en/products/professional-graphics/instinct-mi25) used in Azure's [`NVv4-Series`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/nvv4-series) does not appear to support any video acceleration [(Datasheet PDF)](https://www.amd.com/system/files/documents/radeon-instinct-mi25-datasheet.pdf).

I had some luck using the [DirectX backend](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#DXVA2) which uses the general-purpose GPU cores for decoding, but ended up switching to Azure's NVIDIA-based VMs which have both decoding and encoding support.

Comment: Yes, we reached the same conclusion and also switched to the NVIDIA's